# Try-catch slowing down simulation of linear mixed effects

Tags: r, try-catch, convergence

I am simulating linear mixed effects in R, but sometimes the model does not converge. Therefore, I wrap it in a `try` function so the simulation keeps running even if the model fails. However, my simulation is very slow, and I think it's because of my code. I wrap the model in `try` and if it works, then I do the model again, which I know will eat up my time. There has to be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Here is some sample code:

```
set.seed(16420)
y=rnorm(10000,100,15)
x=rnorm(10000,100,15)
t=rep(seq(1,100,1),100)
i=sort(rep(seq(1,100,1),100))
my.data=data.frame(i,t,x,y)
if(!inherits(try(lme(y~x+t,random=~x+t|i,data=my.data),
                 silent=T),"try-error"))
{
  m1=lme(y~x+t,random=~x+t|i,data=my.data)
}
summary(m1)
```

Comment: The title "Trying and not having to do it again" is probably too vague to get much attention for the question. I don't know enough about the question to retitle it for you, but you might want to get more descriptive

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed it.

Comment: Why don't you actually use `tryCatch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple first step you could take to speed up your code (by almost 100%) is to not run the `lme()` model twice; assign the result of `try(lme(...))` to `m1` and *then* test to see if it inherits an error; compare your code from above (placed into a function) to a function with this approach:

```r
sim_slow <- function() {
    y=rnorm(10000,100,15)
    x=rnorm(10000,100,15)
    t=rep(seq(1,100,1),100)
    i=sort(rep(seq(1,100,1),100))
    my.data=data.frame(i,t,x,y)
    if(!inherits(try(nlme::lme(y~x+t,random=~x+t|i,data=my.data), silent=T),"try-error"))
    {
        return(nlme::lme(y~x+t,random=~x+t|i,data=my.data))
    }
    return(NULL)
}

sim_fast <- function(no_warn = TRUE) {
    if ( no_warn ) { # If you also don't want the warnings
        warn_option <- getOption("warn")
        options(warn = -1)
        on.exit(options(warn = warn_option))
    }
    y <- rnorm(10000, 100, 15)
    x <- rnorm(10000, 100, 15)
    t <- rep(seq(1, 100,1), 100)
    i <- sort(rep(seq(1, 100, 1), 100))
    my.data <- data.frame(i, t, x, y)
    m1 <- try(nlme::lme(y ~ x + t, random = ~x + t|i, data = my.data), silent = TRUE)
    return("if"(inherits(m1, "try-error"), NULL, m1))
}
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Now let's see if there's a speed difference:

```r
set.seed(16420)
system.time(slow_sims <- replicate(10, sim_slow()))
#> Warning in logLik.lmeStructInt(lmeSt, lmePars): Singular precision matrix
#> in level -1, block 1

#> Warning in logLik.lmeStructInt(lmeSt, lmePars): Singular precision matrix
#> in level -1, block 1

#> (Many similar warnings are omitted here for space)

#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  19.612   0.008  19.621
set.seed(16420)
system.time(fast_sims <- replicate(10, sim_fast()))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  11.704   0.000  11.703
sum(sapply(slow_sims, is.null))
#> [1] 3
sum(sapply(fast_sims, is.null))
#> [1] 3
all.equal(slow_sims, fast_sims)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>